# irreducible components of $\operatorname{Spec}R$, where $R=k[X,Y,Z]/(XY)$, $k$ is a field.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

The task is to find all the irreducible components of $\operatorname{Spec} R$, where $R=k[X,Y,Z]/(XY)$, $k$ is a field. And, the solution says that the components are $\operatorname {Spec} k[X,Y,Z]/(X)$ and $\operatorname{Spec} k[X,Y,Z]/(Y)$ because $k[X,Y,Z]/(X)\simeq k[Y,Z]$ which is an integral domain which implies $\operatorname{Spec} k[X,Y,Z]/(X)$ is irreducible.

I don't understand why $k[X,Y,Z]/(X)$ being an integral domain implies $\operatorname{Spec} k[X,Y,Z]/(X)$ is irreducible because what I know is that this only tells us that $(X)$ is a prime ideal in $k[X,Y,Z]$. I know that I am missing some background result but I am unable to figure it out. Could someone point it out to me?

Also, there is a result that for a ring $R$, the irreducible components of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ are given by $V(\mathfrak{p})$, where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal of $R$. Then how do I get these prime ideals here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some useful facts.

(i) $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is irreducible $\iff$ the nilpotent ideal $\sqrt{(0)}$ of $R$ is prime ideal.

(ii) For integral domain $R$, $\sqrt{(0)}=(0)$ is prime ideal.

(iii) If $\operatorname{Spec} R$ is integral,  then it is irreducible.

(iv) If scheme $X$ is integral, then it is irreducible.

(i) and (ii) is ring theory, (iii) is induced by (i),(ii). And (iv) is generalization of (iii).

---

In your example, minimal prime ideal of $k[X,Y,Z]/(XY)$ correspond to minimal prime ideal which contains $(XY)\subset k[X,Y,Z]$.

Now for minimal prime ideal $(XY)\subset {\frak p}\subset k[X,Y,Z]$, because of $XY\in {\frak p}$, we get $X\in  {\frak p}$ or $Y\in  {\frak p}$. And $(X)$ and $(Y)$ satisfy this condition.

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Comment: I've slightly edited your post. The use of three dashes in a row, i.e. `---` will produce a horizontal separator bar.